# Persistent volume claim getting stuck in Pending mode

Tags: storage, kubernetes

I have just configured openebs as the storageclass type on k0s but when I then attempt to create a persistent volume claim it gets stuck in **Pending** mode.

As a check to satisfy the ***WaitForFirstConsumer*** constraint I created a deployment but after some time the persistent volume claim still remains in Pending mode.

I am pretty sure storageclass is configured well now (unless otherwise !) because when I run `k0s kubectl get storageclass` I get :

```
openebs-device openebs.io/local Delete WaitForFirstConsumer false 11h
openebs-hostpath openebs.io/local Delete WaitForFirstConsumer false 11h
```

For context my local-pvc.yaml is as below:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: mssql-claim
spec:
  storageClassName: openebs.io/local
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 200Mi
```

This one however gives an error after I add the storageClassName attribute (***Is the attribute mandatory for provisioning of the pvc? If so whats the exact value?*** ).

The original deployment doesnt contain the attribute though and I had to add it after some digging around. Im not entirely sure about which value i should configure for **storageClassName: value**.

What am I missing ?

Comment: As I understand, you provided `spec.storageClassName: openebs.io/local` But, according to your output, it seems not a name, but `provisioner`.  Can you try to change as `spec.storageClassName: openebs-device` or `spec.storageClassName: openebs-hostpath` if those are your StorageClass names?

Comment: @AndrewSkorkin No change same error even after amending to openebs-device. After doing  ks describe pod mssql-depl-86c86b5f44-ldj48 I saw that the error is something to do with the node :  " Warning  FailedScheduling  10m (x6 over 16m)  default-scheduler  0/1 nodes are available: 1 node(s) had taint {node-role.kubernetes.io/master: }, that the pod didn't tolerate.
"

Comment: I fixed this before with k0s kubectl taint nodes serverfxc02 node-role.kubernetes.io/master- and it worked but for now its not working

Comment: Can you list your node? `kubectl get node`

Comment: yes I can list nodes

Comment: NAME          STATUS   ROLES           AGE   VERSION
serverfxc02    Ready    control-plane   27h   v1.23.1+k0s